# how to create httpclient for delete request with application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: java, rest, http, url, http-delete

i am creating this request but it is working as get method not like delete

```
 `public static void main(String[] args)  {     
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
    try {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
      .url("https://qa.ecourierz.com/api/v1/bookings/ECZ159616")
      .delete()
      .addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8")
      .addHeader("x-api-token", "5dfb3ef7c11e1756916bb997-933f79708364c553a7c7352e7d2a6824cd48d8ed")
      .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
      .build();
        Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
        String body = response.body().string();
        System.out.println("body  "+body);
        System.out.println( "response---------------------    "+ response);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("hello");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i am creating this code for httpdelete request.i am getting response code as 200 but it is working like get request as the order status is not getting changed in response please help

Comment: I am getting the result `{"status": "error", "errors": [{"status_code": 401, "error_code": "", "location": "header", "name": "X-API-Token", "description": "Kindly verify your X-API-Token. No User exists with the provided Token"}]}`

Comment: using this X-API-Token  5dfb3ef7c11e1756916bb997-933f79708364c553a7c7352e7d2a6824cd48d8ed and the above url hit using postman the response is comming

Comment: **"description": "Kindly verify your X-API-Token. No User exists with the provided Token"**